# Simple Mootools to jQuery conversion - Event Handler

Tags: jquery, mootools

I'm in the middle of porting a MooTools plugin over to jQuery but having never used MooTools before I'm stuck on a small section which I'm hoping someone can help with.

MooTools:

```
var bt = new Element('a',{
    "title" : label,
    "text"  : label,
    "class" : classe,
    "events": {
        click: (clickEvent || this.hide).bind(this)
    }
});

this.buttons.push(btn);
return btn;
```

My jQuery so far:

```
var btn = $('a').attr({
    "title" : label,
    "text"  : label,
    "class"  : cssClass
});

btn.click(function() {

});
```

I'm just not sure how to convert the click handler line from MooTools...?

**EDIT: Here's the full function:**

```
addButton : function(label, cssClass, clickEvent) {

    // jQuery code
    var btn = $('<a></a>').attr({
        "title" : label,
        "text"  : label,
        "class"  : cssClass
    });

    btn.click(function() {

    });

    // Mootools code
    var bt = new Element('a',{
        "title" : label,
        "text"  : label,
        "class" : classe,
        "events": {
            click: (clickEvent || this.hide).bind(this)
        }
    });

    this.buttons.push(btn);
    return btn;
},
```

It's part of a Modal window plugin so add this point it's checking to see what buttons it's meant to be adding. If the callback function is passed then it will act on it, if not then it will hide the Modal window... I think...

**NOTE:** Just to point out I've also slightly changed the parameter and variable names in the jQuery version. It's not a typo.

Comment: what does the event actually do ?

Comment: does it matter? `btn.click(clickEvent || namespace.hide);` - the bind in mootools is here to keep the context pointing to the class itself, which won't exist in jquery so no point. this will set the callback to a `clickEvent` fn (if not falsy) or call `something.hide` instead - with first argument being the event and whatever way jquery wraps things, i wouldn't know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var btn = $('<a></a>').attr({
    "title" : label,
    "text"  : label,
    "class" : cssClass
}).click(function(e) {
    //Click event logic (I think you're trying to hide it)
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Or, you could write it like this:

```
var btn = $('<a></a>').attr({
    "title" : label,
    "text"  : label,
    "class" : cssClass
    "click" : function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Or, like this:

```
var btn = $('<a></a>').attr('title', label)
                      .attr('text', label)
                      .attr('class', cssClass)
                      .click(function(e) {
                                             e.preventDefault();
                                             $(this).hide();
                                         });
```

Comment: Yes, I did originally chain the .click() event but I just thought it read slightly better when separated. Is there any difference between either way?

Comment: Isn't the mootools only binding hide to the click if clickEvent is a falsy value ?

Comment: Ian, I don't think it matters either way. @Esailija, honestly, I'm not sure what MooTools is doing. I'll update if clarified.

Comment: @JamesHill, unless `clickEvent` is some mootools global, it should be included in jQuery logic as well.

Comment: Ah, I can pass "click" as an attribute? I didn't know that. That's a neater solution. I'll change my code to match. As for the action I'm not sure it's trying to prevent default. It's part of the "addButton" function and this is part of a modal plugin so I think it's basically saying if a callback function is passed then act on that function but if not then hide the modal window.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the full function which should help to shed some light on things. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: the problem isn't the click but the context of `this` which is not the  element as this answer assumes

Comment: @Esailija, are you saying that `$(this)` inside the click event doesn't refer to the `a` that was just creating?

Comment: no I am saying that it **is refering** to the a element, but in the original mootools code it refers to the modal window class. not the a element. Also, `hide` in the original mootools code bound to click is a method of the modal window class.

Comment: @Esailija no, it isn't a mootools 'global' :). `clickEvent` is likely a named argument (hence the || fallback when null).

Answer (score 0):

This part needs to be rewritten. The mootools plugin is actually creating a new anchor; the code you have is going to select all anchors on the page and apply the attrs to them (actually it probably just affects the first selected anchor, but still a problem).

```
var btn = $('a').attr({
    "title" : label,
    "text"  : label,
    "class  : cssClass
});
```

It doesn't answer your question, but it's something you needed to know.

Comment: yeah, it should be `$('<a></a>')`

Comment: Ah, good spot! Thanks for pointing that out Chris and thanks for the tip Nathan. This is the first time of using either library as I've only just started learning Javascript and jQuery this week. It's all useful info. No doubt I'll be making several errors along the way but useful learning none the less.

Answer (score 0):

```
addButton : function(label, cssClass, clickEvent){
var btn = $('<a>');

btn.attr({
"title" : label,
"text"  : label,
"class"  : cssClass
}).click( $.proxy( ( clickEvent || this.hide ), this )  );

this.buttons.push( btn );
return btn;
}
```

Notes:

`$.proxy( fn, context )` is functionally equivalent to  `fn.bind( context )`

It's much better to use `.click(fn)` than `attr("click", fn)` because the former gets 
jQuery cross browser event fixes.

Comment: Pretty much. I've updated my original question to show the parameters passed. The callback function is the last one passed in.

Comment: well the code is already a jQuery port, just add the parameters to the method and uncomment

Comment: OK, I'll give that a go. .proxy() does seem to be a good fit given the context of 'this'.

Comment: yes `this` refers to the modal window class, **not the element**. and `this.hide` refers to a hide method in the modal window class, not `.hide()` in jQuery